# Is there any official documentation that mentions the creation of files in /tmp folder by Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Based on my observations, I understand that Selenium WebDriver creates files (created during execution) in `/tmp` folder and then deletes them when `driver.quit()` is called.

Is there any official Selenium WebDriver documentation that mentions this and throws more details around it?

I want to learn:

1. Is the `/tmp` location configurable by the developer in the code?
2. Can this be turned off?

Comment: You may be able to change the location with the `java.io.tmpdir` system property.

Comment: Can this be configured via Maven?

Comment: If you are running via the failsafe plugin you should be able to use `systemPropertyVariables`.